# Problema com rota no Laravel; minha página não acessa os arquivos do bootstrap que estão na página de layout

Tags: css, laravel, url, route

gostaria de uma forcinha, estou iniciando com o laravel 6 e estou com o seguinte problema;

Possuo uma página de layout dentro da pasta "views>layouts" que se chama "admin.blade.php":

[image: Página de Layout do módulo admin]

Nela estão os meus arquivos do bootstrap e jQuery e etc. Página "admin.blade.php":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Adcionando dependencias -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <title> @yield('title') </title>
</head>
<header >

 <!-- Menu da página --> 

</header>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

</body>
<footer>

 <!-- Rodapé da página --> 

</footer>
</html>
```

Aqui estão as minhas rotas:

```html
//Admin
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
Route::get('/admin/usuarios', 'UsuariosController@index');
```

As rotas direcionam para a controller que direciona para os devidos arquivos.
Quando eu acesso a página index do módulo admin dentro de "views>admin>index.blade.php" estendendo a página de layout:

```html
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('title')
    Index
@endsection

@section('content')

<!-- Corpo da página -->

@endsection
```

Nos recursos do Google Chrome o diretório de busca dos arquivos do bootstrap é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma eu consigo acessar os arquivos do bootstrap e tudo ocorre bem, porém quando eu tento acessar a index de usuarios do módulo admin, no seguinte diretório "views>admin>usuarios>index.blade.php", estendendo da mesma forma a página de layout admin, o diretório de busca dos arquivos do bootstrap fica sendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com esse "admin" no meio da Request Url, desse modo eu não consigo mais acessar os arquivos do bootstrap e a página perde a estilização.

Gostaria de saber o porque desse problema e como resolver.
Desde já abraços! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta chamar os arquivos do bootstrap e jquery utilizando um helper do laravel chamado asset:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Adcionando dependencias -->

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

    <!-- JS-->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

    <title> @yield('title') </title>
</head>
<header >

 <!-- Menu da página --> 

</header>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

</body>
<footer>

 <!-- Rodapé da página --> 

</footer>
</html>
```